# Rspec how to stub module instance method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

B.rb looks like:

```
module A
   module B

     def enabled? xxx
        xxx == 'a'
     end

     def disabled? xxx
       xxx != 'a'
     end
   end
end
```

Another C.rb like:

```
module YYY
  class C
  include A::B

  def a_method 
     if(enabled? xxx) 
       return 'a'
     return 'b'
  end
end
```

Now I want to write unit tests to test a_method function,

```
 describe :a_method do
    it 'returns a' do
       ###how to sub enabled? method to make it return true....
    end
 end
```

enabled? is the instance method in the model, I tried

```
A::B.stub.any_instance(:enabled).and_return true
```

it doesn't work.

anyone can help me????

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are stubbing wrongly. Your `A::B` is a module, so you don´t have instances, instances are of classes. You forget the question mark also.

Try this to stub your module static method:

```
A::B.stub(:enabled?).and_return true
```

And in the second example (if you need) try this:

```
YYY::C.any_instance.stub(:a_method).and_return something
```

But I think you are trying to stub the `enabled?` method in the class `YYY::C`, so you need to use this:

```
YYY::C.any_instance.stub(:enabled?).and_return true
```

Then when calling :a_method, `enabled?` will return true.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to stub the method on the class you are creating an instance of.
eg

```
class Z
   include YYY
end

describe Z do
  describe "Z#a_method" do
    let(:z) { Z.new }
    it 'returns a' do
      expect(z).to receive(:enabled?).and_return(true)
      expect(z.a_method).to eq('a')
    end
  end
end
```

or similar...

Comment: Is there another way  if I want to stub the module instance method ?

Comment: I think you need to help us understand why you need to do it the way you want before I can help with any other way.

Comment: there seem to be two problems with `A::B.stub.any_instance(:enabled).and_return true` 1) the method is `enabled?` not `enabled` 2) modules don't really have instances... classes do. So to stub an instance of a class... you have to have a class that includes the module. Incidentally: `any_instance _of`is a costly method to use, compared with just actually making an instance and testing that. That's why I did it the way I did above. The above way is the standard way of testing...

Comment: It's too complicated to explain it. I have to use module, not class

Comment: Then it's too complicated for me to help you :(
Take your time - you have time to explain it. If you can explain it, then we can help you, but otherwise we can't.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but it still pops up when searching for `rspec rails stub a method`.

Although `allow_any_instance_of` and `expect_any_instance_of` both work in this situation, this is considered to be smelly code, for a number of reasons.

I was having difficulty implementing the answer by @Taryn, but my problem was how the test instance was being declared.

```
class Z
   include YYY
end

def outer_test
   Z.new
end

describe Z do

  def inner_test
     Z.new
  end

  # this passes
  describe "Z#a_method" do
    let(:z) { Z.new }
    it 'returns a' do
      expect(z).to receive(:enabled?).and_return(true)
      expect(z.a_method).to eq('a')
    end
  end

  # these will not
  describe "Z#a_method" do
    it 'returns a' do
      expect(outer_test).to receive(:enabled?).and_return(true)
      expect(outer_test.a_method).to eq('a')
    end
  end

  describe "Z#a_method" do
    it 'returns a' do
      expect(inner_test).to receive(:enabled?).and_return(true)
      expect(inner_test.a_method).to eq('a')
    end
  end


end
```

I needed to be careful to ensure that the test class instance declaration was done in a `let` block for this type of stubbing to be successful. But `allow_any_instance_of` and `expect_any_instance_of` will both allow those failing tests to pass.